# HTML input text with customizable spellcheck wavy line

Tags: html, css

I need an HTML input text with configurable wavy red line under words which are not part of a controlled vocabulary. For instance, if my vocabulary is `['foo', 'bar']`, and the text `foo and bar` is entered in the input text, `and` should be underlined because it is not part of the vocabulary.

I don't know where to start from because:

- on the one hand, this is exactly the way google search box is working and it seems to be done with `<input type='text'>`
- on the other hand, there seems to be no way to style only a part of the text in an `<input type='text'>`, and I see some answers on SO stating that this could be done using the `contenteditable` attribute.

So, where is the truth ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the HTML5 spellcheck attribute.

And this for the wavy underline css

```
content: '~';
  position: absolute;
  left:0%;
  transform:scale(16,2);
  transform-origin: left
```

Comment: AFAIK,  the spellcheck attribute won't let you have your own vocabulary; it is only true/false